# How do we return multiple plots in R through plumber?

Tags: r, asp.net-web-api, data-visualization, data-analysis, plumber

This is what my code looks like

```
    library(plumber)
    data(mtcars)
    test=mtcars
    #' @get /graph
    #' @png
    makePlot <- function(){
      par(mfrow=c(2,1))
      hist(test$mpg)
      hist(test$wt)
    }

    r <- plumb("plum_api.R") 
    r$run(port=8000)
```

But in the output I see only one graph.

Comment: The code is not reproducible. Did you mean to use the data-set `mtcars` instead of `mpg`?

Comment: @AdamQuek yeah..done the correction!

Comment: To return multiple plots, you can put all plots generated in base64 in a json.
To do this you can consult: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409363/convert-r-image-to-base-64

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to the problem, but a personal test of the code given above.
I created the file `myfile.R` with the following code:

```
# myfile.R

#* @get /graph
#* @png
makePlot <- function(){
      data(mtcars)
      test=mtcars
      par(mfrow=c(2,1))
      hist(test$mpg)
      hist(test$wt)
}
```

and then I ran within R the following commands:

```
r <- plumb("myfile.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

This is what I got from the browser:

[image]

Hope this can help you.