# How to convert simple R plot image to base64 encoding without reading/writing image file to disk first?

Tags: r, ggplot2, base64

How can I convert a plot image to base64 encoding without writing it to disk first (i.e. directly from the R environment)?

Note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409363/convert-r-image-to-base-64) shows how to do it from an image file. I am unable to use files since I am running this in an environment with an R interpreter only (i.e. ephemeral storage only)

I have tried using `base64Encode()` like so

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
ds <- plyr::ddply(df, "gp", plyr::summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))

a <- ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) 

library(RCurl)
a %>% base64Encode(.)
```

But this simply converts the underlying plot data (not the image itself) to base64.

How can I convert an image from the R environment to base64?

Comment: Even with your "ephemeral storage only", can you not use `tempfile` to produce temporary files?

Comment: I replied under your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` object, as you identified, is not an actual plot, but the "raw data from the plot". Strictly speaking, it's a representation of what you want plotted, the mapping between variables and elements, and all the aesthetics (theme, colours, etc.). Try the following:

```
str(a, max.level=1)
```

(and increment `max.level` bit by bit).

When you view `a` in the console, R is actually calling `print(a)` - that's why you will not get the plot outputted if you just run a script from a command line where you try to output a plot by calling `a` by itself.

When calling `print(a)` (or indirectly from an interactive session), ggplot2 builds the plot by mapping the variables to the x- and y-axis, colours, maps out facets, etc. etc. The result of *that* is then drawn on a graphical device, either a plot window or a file. You can actually catch the graphical representation of this drawing with `ggplotGrob` and then further manipulate the actual drawing, before it is sent to the screen or file.

How does this help?

You need to use `print(a)` instead of directly encode `a` (as you have noticed).

I.e. to produce a base64-encoded plot, you can do:

```
library(base64enc)
## convert image to base64 encoded string

fn <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
png(fn)
print(a)
dev.off()

base64enc::base64encode(fn)
```

**But**: This does require you can write to temporary files. And to be honest, I have a hard time believing you are prevented from this.

And unfortunately, I am not aware of any graphical devices (png, bmp, etc.) were you can write directly to a memorystream or variable instead of a physical file.

Comment: In my case I was using a PAAS (heroku) that had idiosyncratic rules about where I could write to, so didn't have access to temporary locations that `tempfile()` tries to access. Instead, I did find a solution by googling the PAAS documentation to learn directly where it *would* allow me to write to, and generating my own DIY temporary files (hacky it may be), like so: `runif(1, 1000000000, 9999999999) %>% round %>% as.character %>% paste0("tmp/", ., ".png")`. Thanks for the answer and explanation

Comment: TBH, wading through this was good learning, as I wasn't even aware plots had to be 'written' before they existed (I assumed they could existing solely in RAM). I am still not sure if it's a convention unique to R, or if that's how all graphics work

Comment: If you **know** where you can create temporary files, you can specify this as an argument: `tempfile(tempdir="tmp/", fileext=".png")` (possibly without trailing slash).

Comment: Regarding the requirement for writing to file, AFAIK, it's purely due to the backend png/jpeg/bmp libraries used. If you peak into `png`, it calls `.External(C_devga, paste0("png:", filename), ...`

Answer (score -1):

it seems to work with objects from a certain type. The class of the object when you used `ggplot()` is not the same than when you used `plot()`.

```
class(a)
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
class(my_plot)
# [1] "NULL"
```

Why not using `ggplot()` all the time ?

```
my_ggplot <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:6, y = c(1,3,6,2,7,5))) + geom_point()

my_ggplot %>% base64Encode(.)
# [1] "bGlzdCgp"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "base64"
```

Comment: While `my_ggplot %>% base64Encode(.)` from your example doesn't error, the base64 output ("bGlzdCgp") actually converts to `list()` (not an image, but a string). See [here](https://www.base64decode.org/)

Comment: I just realised that so does the other one I posted in the question. So I'm not actually converting to images as I thought, but rather converting a string representation of the raw data from the plot

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that I require the image, hope this is useful